# Google Voice API for AIR|Flex

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, google-voice

With the release of AIR 2.5 for Android Flex-developers gain access various system API of the operating system. Are there any official (or unofficial) APIs Google Voice for ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find unofficial java api for google voice ( http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/ ) and integrated it with flex front-end via BlazeDS and RemoteObject.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't any APIs in AIR 2.5 for Google Voice. But you can try using navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://maps.google.com")) as an alternative.

Hope that helps.

Mohit